# How to set a backgroundImage URL with props

Tags: reactjs, url, material-ui

I am trying to make a react component, where background image changes with the props.

Any Idea on how to make it work?

I am getting an object as props, where synmain is a string link to an image " ../image.png"

```
const classes = useStyles(props);

const useStyles =  makeStyles(theme => ({
mainSection:props =>(    {
           backgroundImage: "url(props.synmain)",} ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backticks for string interpolation

It should look something like this:

```
const useStyles =  makeStyles(theme => ({
mainSection:props =>(    {
        backgroundImage: `url(${props.synmain})` ...
```

also try adding these properties to the image

```
backgroundImage: `url(${props.synmain})`,
        backgroundPosition: 'center', 
        backgroundSize: 'cover', 
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        height: '100vh',
        width: '100vw',
        display: 'flex',
        margin: 'auto',
```

I'm not really sure why, but I believe it should fix the issue of not showing the image.. If it doesn't maybe you should try making a standalone image with statically typed url to see if maybe the url is the problem

Comment: Thanks. it really displays the right link in the firefox inspector, but does not display the image itself.

Comment: Okay, so basically you need to add some more properties to the image itself (margins, positions, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  mainSection: {
    backgroundImage: (props) => `url${props.synmain}`,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You have extra `(` in `url$(props`. Also it's the same answer of @someguy.